Migrating RDS Read Replica to Redshift via DMS
I am trying to set up an ongoing CDC migration from a RDS Postgres to Redshift via DMS. I am worried that this might have a performance impact on the db, hence ideally would want to set up the DMS task from a Read Relica instead.
However, I am not sure if this is feasible and read replica overwrites wont yield errors.
How can I approach this? How can I get a better idea on the migration load on the prod db and hence then decide on the right path?
